# Gradle XML Dependency Report Errors

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I'm trying to use the Gradle [`plugin: 'project-report'`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/project_report_plugin.html) to generate dependency reports.

When running the [`gradle htmlDependencyReport`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.reporting.dependencies.HtmlDependencyReportTask.html) task, I can get `html` reports, but when I configure it to produce `xml`, as shown by the example in the documentation, I get an error.

```
// build.gradle
htmlDependencyReport {
    projects = project.allprojects
    reports {
        html {
          enabled false
        }
        xml.destination "build/reports/myReport.xml"
    }
}
```

```
~# gradle htmlDependencyReport

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/Users/the_storyteller/Projects/my_project/build.gradle' line: 84

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'my_project'.
> Could not get unknown property 'xml' for Report set of type org.gradle.api.reporting.dependencies.internal.DefaultDependencyReportContainer.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 0s
```

Do I need an additional plugin, or is my syntax invalid?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suppose, that it's not supported for the report type you are building. [Here is](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/reporting/Reporting.html) an interface description, which is implemented by `HtmlDependencyReportTask`. It specifies a method to configure report container by closure as follows:

> Allow configuration of the report container by closure.
>
> ```
> reports {   
>    html {
>     enabled false   
>    }   
>    xml.destination "build/reports/myReport.xml" 
> }
> ```

It allow you to specify a closure to configure supported reports. Just an example for some of the implementations. And when you look at the javadoc for `HtmlDependencyReportTask` it just shows you parent class method description, which is just an example for some kind of report, not actually for `HtmlDependencyReportTask`.

So, it seems, that you can't actually get an xml report withe html-based report type task. If you take a look at the `DefaultDependencyReportContainer`  [sources](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/diagnostics/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/reporting/dependencies/internal/DefaultDependencyReportContainer.java) you won't find any property named `xml`.

Comment: Unfortunately, when I tried this solution I am getting below error:

Caused by: org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject$CustomMessageMissingMethodException: Could not find method destination() for arguments [.../app/build/reports/jacoco/jacocoTestReport.xml] on Report xml of type org.gradle.api.reporting.internal.TaskGeneratedSingleFileReport.